# How pass apple payload to payfort in magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, payment-gateway

how pass apple payload to payfort in magento2 this is my code for apple pay

$validationUrl="https://apple-pay-gateway-nc-pod5.apple.com/paymentservices/startSession";
$pemPwd = getenv("aalogics123");
$domainName = getenv("Jumla-sa.com");
$merchantId = getenv("merchant.test.applepay");
// JSON Payload 
$validationPayload = '{"merchantIdentifier": "merchant.aalogics.applepay","domainName": "stage-uk.thetelecomshop.com","displayName":"AppleewrqwerqwePayDemoTestDev15"}';
try{    //setting the curl parameters.
        $ch = curl_init();
        if (FALSE === $ch)
            throw new Exception('failed to initialize');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $validationUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, '/var/www/certs/applepay.crt.pem');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY,'/var/www/certs/apple.key.pem');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, "test123");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $validationPayload);    
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    if (FALSE === $content)
    {
        print_r(curl_error($ch));
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($content);
    // $content is the Apple Response, it should be a merchant session object
    // but may need to do some manipulation here

}catch(Exception $e) {
    trigger_error(sprintf('Curl failed with error #%d: %s', $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()), E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Comment: can you please explain in brief.

Comment: i am integrating applepay with magento payfort currently i am getting this error when i call this url $validationUrl="https://apple-pay-gateway-nc-pod5.apple.com/paymentservices/startSession";

Comment: error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca i got this error

Comment: @ Anas Mansuri ??

Comment: check with this - https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/49912